# Apply SpriteKit Physics only in y direction

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2, skphysicsbody

I want to create a simple game with a jumping ball. Idea is that the ball jumps up and down (in y direction):

[image]

My problem is, that the PhysicsEngine of SpriteKit moves the ball also along the x axis (of course). Is there a way to prevent this?

[image]

Many thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Can you show us some code? How you move your ball?

Comment: Hi Darvydas. I'll add some code later. Have to go to work.

Comment: Would running something like `ball.physicsBody?.velocity.x = 0` in `didSimulatePhysics` work for you?  Not sure how (or if) performance draining that would be.

Comment: inside didSimulatePhysics restrict x velocity    TDfirstBody.physicsBody.velocity=CGVectorMake(0,   TDfirstBody.physicsBody.velocity.dy); you are just overwriteing physics simulation nothing to worry about perforemence

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ball not to move in x axis, you can set its `position.x` to a specified value in the `update()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a node in SpriteKit may be accomplished in a few ways:

1. By using [SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html)
2. By using physics engine and [applyImpulse:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsBody/applyImpulse:) or [applyForce:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsBody/applyForce:) methods
3. By changing directly [velocity](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/velocity) property of node's physics body
4. By changing node's [position](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/position) property

The important thing is when to use what.

**Moving the node with physics**

If you are interested in realistic physics simulation as well as contact detection and you want to make a ball to collide with different objects, or make it affected by gravity fields etc, you should stick to applyImpulse: and applyForce: methods (or you can even change velocity vector of node's physics body). Also, it is not recommended to use SKAction in this case because basically you are pulling the node out of sync with physics simulation (there are many posts on SO about this).

If you are not interested in realistic physics simulation (collisions etc.), but only in contact detection, you can keep physics bodies attached to nodes while using actions for moving. In this case you should set `collisionBitMask` of node's physics body to 0.

**Moving nodes by changing its physics body's velocity property**

This is a regular way to move a node with attached physics body to it.  This might be useful if you want to have a full control of how node should move at any moment. You should't try to move node with actions if you are moving node like this (you should not mix these two techniques).

**Moving nodes with actions**

Actions are very convenient way to move a node. If you are just interested to move a node from point A to point B, then this is the easiest way to go. You can run an action with name and later in your code you can access it by that name, which gives you a full control on that action (you can stop it, pause it or speed it up).

Also, there are methods in SKAction class which let you to move nodes in many different ways in easy manner as well...For example you can move a node along predefined path by using [followPath: duration:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/followPath:duration:) method.

**Moving nodes by changing position property**

You should change node's position property only if you are not interested in realistic physics simulation. You can still take advantage of contact detection and attach physics body to nodes while moving nodes like this.

Answer (score 0):

`SKPhysicsBody` has a property called `allowsRotation`. Set it to `false`. Use this along with the changes to `didSimulatePhysics` answer from above. Reference 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519986-allowsrotation